# How to make If the user clicked example the multiply button, then the answer should appear in red

Tags: javascript

```js
/* This code is for addition and im trying to get the number thats printed out to appear in orange not black */

<script type="text/javascript">
 
function addBy()
{
 var num1, num1, res;
 num1=Number(document.formcalc.txtnum1.value);
 num2=Number(document.formcalc.txtnum2.value);
 res=num1+num2;
 document.formcalc.txtres.value=res;
}
  
document.getElementById("addBy").style.color = "#ff0000";
 
  
</script>

/* This is the html used in the code */
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Calculate</title>

</head>
<body>
 <form name="formcalc">
 Number 1: <input type="text" name="txtnum1">
 <br>
 Numbrer 2: <input type="text" name="txtnum2">
 <br>
 Answer : <input type="text" name="txtres"  <br>
  
 <input type="button" value="Add" onClick="addBy()"> 
 </form>
 
 
</body>
</html>
```

So basically in the function im trying to get the number thats printed out to come out in red

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function addBy()
{
    var num1, num1, res;
    num1=Number(document.formcalc.txtnum1.value);
    num2=Number(document.formcalc.txtnum2.value);
    res=num1+num2;
    document.formcalc.txtres.value=res;     
    document.getElementById("txtres").style.color = "#ff0000";
}

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to give your 'Answer' input tag the id "addBy" (i.e id = "addBy") which you referenced in your JavaScript code. Also close the tag.

****UPDATED ANSWER:**

Improved answer after coming back and looking at the question again.

**First**, your input tag needs to be closed:

```
<input type="text" name="txtres" id="answer" />
```

I have also given it an id of *answer* which will be used make a reference to it in the JavaScript code.

**Second**, in your JavaScript code, change the line that styles the input to:

```
document.getElementById("answer").style.color = "#ff0000";
```

To avoid confusion with the function named *addBy*, I changed the selector in the getElementById call to *answer* in quotes. This is why I gave the id attribute the value of "answer" earlier in the input element for the result.

Answer (score 0):

try this.

```js
function addBy()
  {
    var num1, num1, res;
    num1=Number(document.formcalc.txtnum1.value);
    num2=Number(document.formcalc.txtnum2.value);
    res=num1+num2;
    document.formcalc.txtres.value=res;
  }
  
  document.getElementById("txt_AddBy").style.color = "#ff0000";
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Calculate</title>
</head>
<body>
 <form name="formcalc">
 Number 1: <input type="text" name="txtnum1">
 <br>
 Numbrer 2: <input type="text" name="txtnum2">
 <br>
 Answer : <input id="txt_AddBy" type="text" name="txtres" disabled="disabled"/> <br>
  
 <input type="button" value="Add" onClick="addBy()"/> 
 </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: It did slight changes like adding id in the Answer input field, closing the tags properly and disabled the output text-box in order to stop edit. Its done over @Akeem snippet

Comment: Also got "function not found issue" if i set id and function as same name. so that i choosed "txt_AddBy" as a id of that input field.

Comment: Hi Yilmaz my code is basically a calculator which when a certain type of calculation is done the output would appear in a certain color e.g if I do multiplication of 3x3 the result 9 would appear as red or if I done divison of 3/3 the result 1 would appear in blue

Answer (score 0):

Here is the snipped handling the divide operation also.

```js
function calc(type)
  {
    var num1, num1, res;
    num1=Number(document.formcalc.txtnum1.value);
    num2=Number(document.formcalc.txtnum2.value);
    switch(type){
     case 'add' : {
        res=num1+num2;
        document.formcalc.txtres.value=res;
        document.getElementById("txt_AddBy").style.color = "#ff0000";
        break;
     }
     case 'division' : {
        res=num1/num2;
        document.formcalc.txtres.value=res;
        document.getElementById("txt_AddBy").style.color = "blue";
        break;
     }
    } 
 }
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Calculate</title>
</head>
<body>
 <form name="formcalc">
 Number 1: <input type="text" name="txtnum1">
 <br>
 Numbrer 2: <input type="text" name="txtnum2">
 <br>
 Answer : <input id="txt_AddBy" type="text" name="txtres" disabled="disabled"/> <br>
  
 <input type="button" value="Add" onClick="calc('add')"/>
  <input type="button" value="Divide" onClick="calc('division')"/>
 </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: This answer is the continuation of my previous answer. Also sorry for the late response..

Comment: It's better to add this to your existing answer (just edit it) than to post a new one in this case.